# How to calculate a gradual rounded border on a path in SVG

Tags: svg, raphael, vector-graphics

I'm trying to create a path following linear curved border in SVG. A bit like this:

[image: linear rounded border corner]

I was wondering how can this be calculated in SVG path syntax? I tried some options, but haven't got anywhere close.

For the record, I'm using Raphael.js - but the question is generic as Raphael don't wrap an API around svg path declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [elliptical arc curve command](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) for this.

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);
var rx = 35,
    ry = 25;
var path = "M20,20v100a" + rx + "," + ry + " 90 0,0 " + ry + "," + rx;
paper.path(path);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/narW4/)

Raphael's `.rect()` method allows for a radius for the corners as well if you need to make a rectangle.

Comment: Do you know any good tutorial with more detail about arc curve?

Comment: I don't, but you can get the hang of it pretty easily with trial and error.

Comment: It seems like arc curves ain't calculated the same way if they're a subpath, do you know anything about this? I made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vaxilart/m6cHw/3/